# How to understand this delegator

Tags: delegates, javassist, activejdbc

I'm reading the source of [activejdbc](http://code.google.com/p/activejdbc), found these methods in [ModelInstrumentation](http://code.google.com/p/activejdbc/source/browse/trunk/activejdbc-instrumentation/src/main/java/org/javalite/instrumentation/ModelInstrumentation.java).

```
public void instrument(CtClass modelClass) throws Exception {
    addDelegates(modelClass);
    CtMethod m = CtNewMethod.make("public static String getClassName() { return \"" + modelClass.getName()
            + "\"; }", modelClass);
    CtMethod getClassNameMethod = modelClass.getDeclaredMethod("getClassName");
    modelClass.removeMethod(getClassNameMethod);
    modelClass.addMethod(m);
}

CtClass modelClass = ClassPool.getDefault().get("org.javalite.activejdbc.Model");

private void addDelegates(CtClass target) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {
    CtMethod[] modelMethods = modelClass.getDeclaredMethods();
    CtMethod[] targetMethods = target.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (CtMethod method : modelMethods) {

        if (Modifier.PRIVATE == method.getModifiers()) {
            continue;
        }

        CtMethod newMethod = CtNewMethod.delegator(method, target);

        if (!targetHasMethod(targetMethods, newMethod)) {
            target.addMethod(newMethod);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Detected method: " + newMethod.getName() + ", skipping delegate.");
        }
    }

}
```

This class is used to enhance a model class, the first one `instrument` will firstly delegate all non-private methods from `org.javalite.activejdbc.Model` to its child model class, which means it will add such methods to the child:

```
public X f(...) {
    return super.f(...);
}
```

I don't understand why it does this, since we can invoke these methods even if there is no delegates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation of this can be found in this discussion:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/activejdbc-group/l6KNBi5EPc0

Basically, the main problem is that the methods in the Model class that we need in a child class are static. Static classes in Java are not inherited. This means that when you do this:

```
Person.where(...)
```

You will be executing the method Model.where(), not the Person.where(), hence the framework would have no idea what table to query. 
[ActiveJDBC](http://code.google.com/p/activejdbc/) forces Model methods into child methods in order to at run time determine what table to go to for data.